# Export to CSV with i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, csv, mongoid

When exporting from MongoDB to csv I get my current i18n locale, is it possible to filter this out?

`{"sv"=>"hejsan"}`

I would like this to be only `hejsan`.

Participant.rb (model)

```
class Participant < Model
   ...
    def self.to_csv(options = {})
      CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
        csv << Participant.fields.keys
        all.each do |participant|
          csv << participant.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end
      end
   end
end
```

Model.rb (model)

```
class Model
    include Mongoid::Document
    def self.column_names
    self.fields.collect { |field| field[0] }
    end
end
```

Controller

```
def index
    @participants = Participant.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @participants }
      format.csv { send_data @participants.to_csv }
      format.xls
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you provide us the code you're using to generate this ?

Comment: @Dogbert - Look at update, values_at().